# Have you come across an a-frame component which acts as a chat window? If so, where?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am looking to see if an a-frame component which acts as a virtual chat window already exists. A user can see messages he has sent as well as received.

Comment: What is an "A-frame"?

Comment: a-frame is a framework for WebVr. See: https://aframe.io/ @Dai

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would one of those the `html2canvas/texture` components:

- https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-html-shader
- https://github.com/richardanaya/aframe-html

project the texture on an entity and set up the chat functionality with any of those helpdesk-like chat apps or from scratch.